# WinSCP .NET SynchronizeDirectories is not deleting local files after they've been removed from the remote folder

Tags: c#, winscp-net

I'm attempting to perform a synchronization of files from the remote location to the local path using the WinSCP .NET library, so that files that are new or updated in the source folder are downloaded to the destination, and files that are in the destination and have been removed from the source folder are deleted from the destination.

The call to synchronise is evaluated to something like this:

```
var fileMask = "/FTP_root/Folder_*/*.png>2016-01-01 00:00:00";
var results = session.SynchronizeDirectories(SynchronizationMode.Local,
                                             @"C:\ProjectFolder\AppData",
                                             FTPDirectory,
                                             true,
                                             false,
                                             SynchronizationCriteria.Time,
                                             new TransferOptions() { FileMask = fileMask });
```

To recap, the parameters for SynchronizeDirectories are:

```
SynchronizationMode
LocalPath
RemotePath
RemoveFiles
Mirror
SynchronizationCriteria
TransferOptions
```

What I'm finding with this code is that new and renamed files are downloaded as expected, but files that have been removed from the remote folder are not deleted and, in the case of renamed files, both the old and the new file name are in the local folder after synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synchronization applies the file mask to both the remote and the local path in order to identify which files are applicable to the synchronization, in both directions.

The relevant sections of the File Mask documentation (https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask) are:

- "For a partial path mask it makes no difference whether you use back () or forward slashes (/); the mask will always work for both local and remote paths"
- "You can also specify full path to a specific file or directory, both local and remote"
- "The full path mask matches a local or a remote paths only, depending on syntax used"

In this case, it appears that using a full path mask is causing the mask to be applied only to the remote path. For the synchronisation to support new files, renames and deletions, the path mask should match both remotely and locally, either by using a relative path, e.g.

```
var fileMask = "*/Folder_*/*.png";
```

or by including a mask that matches locally in addition to remotely:

```
var fileMask = @"C:\ProjectFolder\AppData\Folder_*\*.png; /FTP_root/Folder_*/*.png;
```

I have only briefly tested the latter approach but it also appears to work (albeit with some considerations required for size and time constraints in the mask). The relative path approach works in my circumstance, although it isn't exactly equivalent to the full path approach (because it may also match folders lower down the directory hierarchy).